# Getting value from reference cell's next cell

Tags: excel

In a nutshell, I have the following table:

[image: table]

I am using the reference to A2 cell in A15 cell and I am trying the B15 and C15 to show the appropriate numeric values showin in B2 and C2.

How can I archieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on B15. In the cell border, drag the square to the bottom right over to C15 and let go. Done.

This question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the SuperUser, but I'll surely check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Theres an easy way to do it

set `A15 = A$2`

select A15, while clicking A15's lower right corner drag the cursor(cursor will change into a '**+**') to C15, values will automatically filled in.